# how to install open cv wheel package using pip in python?

Tags: python, opencv, pip, python-wheel

I have installed the wheels package and have the latest update of pip but when I try running `pip install opencv.whl` it says "opencv.whl is not a valid wheel filename". I made sure that I'm in the same directory where `opencv.whl` is present. 
I also tried installing the .exe file of opencv but it says:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv3 from versions: 
No matching distributions found for opencv3
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Please make more of an effort on the presentation. If you don't give a shit about your question, why should anyone else?

Comment: Did you rename your wheel file? See the filename convention in [PEP 427](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#file-name-convention) (which saw the introduction to wheel installers). IOW do not rename your wheel installer, the name contains important information like Python version dependencies. Also, provide the full path to the wheel file.

Comment: make sure the version is right